# CSS - Height adjusting to screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive

I always have a bit of difficulty when it comes to sizing and positioning things in css.  I am trying to create a navbar that extends on hover and displays the navbar items.  There are 2 problems that I am facing:

1. The navbars height when extended changes when the width of the page is changed, resulting in content going outside of the navbar.  I need the navbar to be always containing the items placed inside.  (I tried min-height, but it removes the transition effect.  )
2. When the user hovers on the navbar, the navbar items come in before it is fully extended.
3. When my mouse goes over the navbar, it seems to be activated before it even hovers onto the navbar (if you move your mouse slowly, you can see that just before the mouse enters the navbar, it gets triggered).

How would I go about solving these problems?

```css
.menu{
  background: white;
  width:100%;
  height:15vh;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid red;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover{
  height: 40vh;
}
.menu:hover > .menu-item{
  display: block;
}
.menu-item{
  margin:2%;
  font-size:1.6em;
  color:black;
  margin-top: 1.4vh;
  display:none;
  height: 6vh;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid #C0C5CD;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1><a>PostNote</a></h1>
  <br />
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Home</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Notes</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Add a Note</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>My Profile</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For menu item, you can play with **opacity/height** instead of the display and you will get a smooth animation

```css
.menu{
  background: white;
  width:100%;
  min-height:10vh;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid red
}
.menu h1 {
margin:5px 0;
}

.menu:hover > .menu-item{
  opacity:1;
  height: 6vh;
  margin-top: 1.4vh;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
.menu-item{
  margin:2%;
  font-size:1.6em;
  color:black;
  margin-top: 0vh;
  margin-bottom:0;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  height: 0vh;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid #C0C5CD;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1><a>PostNote</a></h1>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Home</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Notes</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>Add a Note</a></p>
  <p class="menu-item"><a>My Profile</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know a solution to the height of the navbar problem as well?

Comment: even with this solution you still have issue ?

Comment: it doesn't fit the size of the childrens height.  In larger browsers, it still is too short.  I want it so that it always is larger than the child elements so that they will never not have enough room

Comment: can you add some background color to the elements and make a screenshoot where you show the issue please, i am not sure i understand well

Comment: I added a red border on the bottom of the navbar indicating the height of the div.  I want it so that when the user hovers on the navbar, it extends the height so that the red border goes past the navbar items.  I mentioned in my question that when the browser size changes, it affects how much the navbar extends.  Also I found a new problem with the navbar and added it to my list of questions above.

Comment: updated my solution with the red border and as you can see it always goes under the item. For the (3) it's due to margin of h1.

Comment: That did help.....although the initial height of the navbar is huge.   When I try to adjust it, nothing happens.  How would I make the initial height 10vh

Comment: you may notice that the height depend on some margin. here we have **p** and **h1** that have margin, i will update my solution by removing some margin (answer updated)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did not notice you added some margins